# NotificationService: Toast already killed

Tags: android, android-toast

When calling show toast message from AIDL service callback toast comes with flicker. I tried with `runOnUiThread()`, handler, etc... in AIDL callback but still it's not solving.

Anyone faced similar issue?

Comment: I came to know that this issue was related to device manufacturers. like custom OS having default restrictions to the notifications and we need to manually turn it on under settings--> App Notifications --> our app--> Categories --> update the settings.

Comment: In my case this warning appeared in LogCat when using `socket.io` library. On any event (connection, error, new message) I showed a `Toast` message in UI thread. It showed normally, but wrote the warning to LogCat.